# Why are the stats different for me and a friend?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I recently played through the first season of The Walking Dead and then a friend brought it a few days later. After she got it and completed the first episode, we decided to share our stats to compare our decisions but noticed that the percentages were completely different even if we had made the same decision.

For example, with episode 2 'Starved For Help', we both chopped David's leg off, but mine says "You and 43% of players chopped his leg off", while hers says "You and 84% of players chopped his leg off". Same decision, different stats.

It's only been a few days difference from when I completed it to when she completed it. So I can't see how it can drastically change that much? And even if it did, surely when I check my stats again, the percentages just update to the latest figures anyway?

The only difference is she is playing on a PS3 and I'm on a PS4, but I wouldn't have thought they'd have separate stats for each version. It's the same for other choices in the game too, we made the same decisions but have different percentages.

I was just wondering if anyone could shed some light on to how it's calculated (without stating the obvious) or why us both making the same decisions give different results?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's different for each console and also for PC.

Comment: If that's true, it's kind of annoying not having a global stat :/

Comment: Huh turns out PS3 players don't have the stones to get the job done

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely because of the different consoles.  I don't remember where I read it, but I remember reading near the beginning of the current generation of consoles that neither the Xbox One nor the PS4 would be able to share leaderboards with each other or with their older counterpart.  It's unfortunate, I know, but it is interesting to see the disparity between the two consoles.  I wonder if it has anything to do with people possibly playing a second play-through on the newer console so they are more willing to make a decision that they were not comfortable with the first time around.

Comment: After playing through on the Xbox 360, I made completely difference choices on the Xbox One.  I would say that approach would factor into differences too.